# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() problem

Tags: python, django-models

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e4G2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO7qo.png)

please solve this problem of django I want to add models in model.py but it is showing this You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.